# Summation involving a hypergeometric 1F1 function

Tags: summation, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to find a closed form for the following:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/4)_n}{n!(3/2)_n}\left(\frac{i}{2\tau}\right)^{n} {_1F_1(2n+1;2n+2;i k)}  
\end{equation}

Using the identity:
\begin{equation}
e^z {_1F_1(a;b;-z)}={_1F_1(b-a;b;z)}  
\end{equation}
i can write 
\begin{align}
{_1F_1(2n+1;2n+2;i k)} = & e^{ik}{_1F_1(1;2n+2;-ik)} \\
=&e^{ik} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_m}{(2n+2)_m}\frac{(-ik)^m}{m!} \\
=&e^{ik} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-ik)^m}{(2n+2)_m}
\end{align}

substituting this back to the first equation
\begin{equation}
e^{ik} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/4)_n}{n!(3/2)_n}\left(\frac{i}{2\tau}\right)^{n} \frac{(-ik)^m}{(2n+2)_m} 
\end{equation}

now im stuck at this part. how do i simplify this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $\tau$ and $k$?

Comment: k is positive, and no restrictions on $\tau$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left(-\dfrac{1}{4}\right)_n}{n!\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)_n}\left(\dfrac{i}{2\tau}\right)^n{_1F_1(2n+1;2n+2;ik)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{(n)}i^n(2n+1)\int_0^1x^{2n}e^{ikx}~dx}{\left(-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^{(n)}n!2^n\tau^n}$

$=\int_0^1e^{ikx}~dx-\dfrac{i}{4\tau}\int_0^1x^2e^{ikx}~dx-\dfrac{25}{96\tau^2}\int_0^1x^4e^{ikx}~dx-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{9}{4}\right)^{(n)}5i^n(2n+5)\int_0^1x^{2n+4}e^{ikx}~dx}{\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{(n)}3(n+2)!2^{n+4}\tau^{n+2}}$

$=\int_0^1e^{ikx}~dx-\dfrac{i}{4\tau}\int_0^1x^2e^{ikx}~dx-\dfrac{25}{96\tau^2}\int_0^1x^4e^{ikx}~dx-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{9}{4}\right)^{(n)}5i^n2^{n-4}(2n+5)\int_0^1x^{2n+4}e^{ikx}~dx}{3(2n)!(n+1)(n+2)\tau^{n+2}}$